# The quantity of price in floating is not showing on msgbox as floating instead of showing integer

Tags: vb6, msgbox

i have a project in vb 6.0. its simple project of a sales purchase. The quantity prices are in floating value but problem is that whenever i made a sales order the prices are in rounded. not in floating value. kindly suggest me what to do

Comment: The first thing I suggest is to tag your question with the right language. VB6 is not VB.NET and vice versa.  Secondly, if your code is not working then your code is wrong but no one is going to be able to tell you what's wrong with it if you keep it secret. Post the relevant code! Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: Without the source code it's really hard to understand what do you mean.

Answer (score 0):

You should casting `floating` or `Integer` to `String` before you use it in msgbox.

The reason is when you are chaining `String` with number it's automatically change it to `Integer`